# SBT can't find the partial unification plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory, bintray, sbt-plugin

addSbtPlugin("org.lyranthe.sbt" % "partial-unification" % "1.1.0") in project/plugins.sbt. 
When running sbt I get

```
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.lyranthe.sbt#partial-unification;1.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Resolving dependencies through Artifactory. Scala version 2.11.12. sbt.version=1.2.0

Comment: It's here https://bintray.com/fiadliel/sbt-plugins/partial-unification

Comment: and https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.lyranthe.sbt/partial-unification/

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/SBT+Repositories

Comment: @DmytroMitin Thanks. I had previously create a sbt-remote repo, but was trying to access it from a virtual repo. When accessed directly it worked.